# Boost::Bind noncopyable error with shared_ptr <tcp::socket>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, shared-ptr, boost-bind

I am trying the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr< tcp::socket > socket(new tcp::socket( *io_service));

boost::bind(&function, *socket); // compiler error: noncopyable error
function(*socket); // this works fine

void
function(tcp::socket & socket)
{
   //do work
}
```

Why do I get an error there using boost::bind?

I later tried the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr< tcp::socket > socket(new tcp::socket( *io_service));
boost::bind(&function, socket); //this works fine now
void function(boost::shared_ptr< tcp::socket > socket)
{
   asio::read_until(&socket, buffer, "end"); // compiler error: says i am passing an invalid argument
}
```

Why doesn't this work now?

I know I am lacking basic knowledge of C/C++ programming.

If anyone could include a link that helps with issues like this, it would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tcp::socket is non-copyable, you need to pass it as a reference:

```
boost::bind(&function, boost::ref(*socket));
```

You should probably stick to your second version as you will not have to worry about life-time of the socket object.

```
boost::bind(&function, socket); 
void function(boost::shared_ptr< tcp::socket > socket)
{
   asio::read_until(*socket, buffer, "end");
}
```

Comment: The issue with the second approach is that I am not being able to read the socket because it is a pointer now. I thought I used &socket_ptr, would give me socket instead of the pointer. Do you know how to go about that?

Comment: You use get() to get the pointer. But that's not what you want to pass, you want to pass a reference to the socket. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to copy a noncopyable object.  Wrap it in a boost::ref object to hold it as a reference:

```
boost::bind(&function, boost::ref(*socket));
```